# Installing packages in a local directory

Tags: installation, package, go, local

What is the best practice to install packages (those with `go get...`) in a local directory?

Example: I'd like to try out the [Revel](http://robfig.github.com/revel/) web framework, but I don't want to clutter my go installation at `/usr/local/go`.

Normally I'd say `sudo go get github.com/robfig/revel` as written on the home page, but that would install it beneath `/usr/local/go/src/pkg/...`.

Is there an easy way to say (for example) `go get --local ...` and have the package in the current (sub) directory?

Comment: Hard to chose which answer to accept. For the moment I've only played with `GOPATH`, so @keks's answer is the one I chose, but this might change in the future :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can export the env variable `GOPATH`. For me it is `~/local/lib/go`. This folder has the subfolders `bin`, `pkg` and `src`, so it's just like `/usr/local/go`. The `go`-tool will then automatically download , build and install packages into this directory.

Answer (score 25):

To expand on keks answer, you can update your .bashrc to look like this

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=~/workspace/me/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Now all packages installed with `go get` are separate from the go distribution.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to consider using [Go Version Manager (gvm)](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm).

Apart from switching between Go versions easily, it also lets you switch between *pkgsets* ("workspaces").

First you create a set

```
gvm pkgset create myproject
```

and then you use it

```
gvm pkgset use myproject
```

Works like a charm.