# golang: go install tries /usr/local instead of GOPATH

Tags: installation, go, local

This is somewhat a follow-up to my last question: [golang: installing packages in a local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514037/golang-installing-packages-in-a-local-directory)

I have `GOPATH` set to `$HOME/prog/go/gopath` and this path exists with three directories:

```
~/prog/go/gopath$ ls
bin  pkg  src
```

Now I try to install a [module to access the redis database](https://github.com/alphazero/Go-Redis) which asks me to run

```
go install
```

inside the source directory. But the command `go install` gives me

```
~/prog/go/gopath/src/redis (go1)$ go install
go install flag: open /usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/flag.a: permission denied
~/prog/go/gopath/src/redis (go1)$ echo $GOPATH 
<myhomedir>/prog/go/gopath
```

(where `<myhomedir>` is a valid path)

Question 1: why does `go install` not take `$GOPATH` into account?
Question 2: how to convince `go install` to use `$GOPATH`?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure how you setup go but it's possible that it needs to build packages from std library but can't due to permissions. You can try

```
cd /usr/local/go/src
sudo ./all.bash
```

This should build the std library and run tests to make sure everything is ok.

Make sure you have proper permissions to read and execute from $GOROOT as necessary. Personally I just download the archive from golang.org and keep it under ~/local/go and set GOROOT appropriately.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what it does. My go installation works fine so far. Never had any problems and even cross compiling works fine.

Comment: do you have permission to read /usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/flag.a ?

Comment: yes, I can read `/usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/flag.a` as my main user

Comment: I had the same issue and running ./all.bash as root fixed it. Not sure what the deal was: my permissions on the .a's were correct and it seemed to be trying to rebuild packages that were already built. Might have something to do with timestamps.

Answer (score 5):

Similar problems here. When I check my $GOROOT, I find that all the libraries are already built there. But for some reasons, it tries to rebuild all the libraries. So I just do a little trick:

```
find /usr/lib/go/pkg/ -name "*.*" | sudo xargs touch
```

Then everything just work fine.

Comment: Because of timestamp differences between the files in $GOROOT/src and $GOROOT/pkg, the pkg files are determined to be out of date and are attempting to be rebuilt. But because they're not writable by the user, there's a permission denied error. Touching each .a file fixes the problem.

Comment: The command I ran was slightly different: `find /usr/local/go -name "*.a" -exec touch -r \`which go\` {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

I think the command you need is "go get":

```
go get github.com/alphazero/Go-Redis
```

will download the Go-Redis library and put it into your $GOPATH/src directory.

go install performs a compile and install on your own source code.

I must admit, I struggled with this whole concept for a bit, but a careful re-reading of "[How to Write Go](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)" and the code organization section contains what you need to know about how the go command works.

Comment: ... btw: the `go get` should be without `https://` from what I have tried. Thanks for the link to "How to Write Go"!

Comment: Isn't GOPATH a list of paths (analogous to PATH)? That's what the documentation says, if I recall correctly. Are you sure you don't mean GOROOT?

Comment: GOROOT points to where the Go binary is installed. GOPATH is a list of Workspaces. There is more detail at http://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is remove GOROOT from your .bash_profile. Then the go command will install it to your GOPATH directory.
And so strange is: when I set the GOROOT in my .bash_profile again and create a new shell, it also works.